# How can I teleport and entity to the exact location of the player while they are moving?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am having trouble making sure that one of the entities is always inside of the player. I am able to get it to teleport to me, but when moving it lags behind which isn't a good thing for what I am trying to do.

```
/execute @a[x=~,y=~0.5,z=~,score_holdingWand_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /tp @e[type=Villager,name=rightClickDetector] @a
```

I want to keep this villager inside the player at all times, even when running and sprinting. If there is a way then that would be great.

Comment: Are you using a 20hz clock to run this command? (I.e repeating command block)

Comment: Yes, the entity is still lagging behind though.

Answer (score 1):

A 20hz clock is the fastest possible way to run a command. There is no way to teleport the villager to the player faster than that. Try using more than 1 villager, possibly arranged in a circle or shpere to always catch a players click. Additionally, if you could get the player to ride something, like a pig or horse, you could make the villager ride that entity as well, and their positions would match. 
Hope this helped

Comment: The riding would be a good idea, but I need the player to move freely. unless you can set the position of an entity riding a player so that they are placed inside of them. If so then that could work.

Comment: Sadly there is no way to get an entity to ride the player. What I meant was if the player was riding a horse or pig, then you could use commands and also put the villager on that horse or pig. Entitydata does not work on the player.

Comment: That's too bad... I guess I will just have to figure out another way around it then...